# Checking if a multi-line string exist in a file

Tags: string, bash, string-comparison

I wanted to make a bash script to check if each line of multi-line string already exist in a file.

I had already wrote some code, but I'm not sure if it will work:

```
str="
this is
a multiple
line
string"

while read -r f; do
    while read -r s: do
       if [ $r == $s ]; then break; fi
    done
done << some_file.txt
```

any ideas to get it working ?

Comment: for a first pass at checking syntax consider pasting your entire code (including shebang) @ [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) then make the recommended changes; as for the comment ... *I'm not sure it will work* ... have you tried running the code? what results do you get?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution in `bash`:

- Reading the string lines into an array.
- Then, for each string line in the array:

  - Checking the file contains a whole line equal to that string line.
  - Stop walking the array once a check fails.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"

names="
this is
a multiple
line
string"

# Read string lines into an array
readarray -t <<< $names

# Walk array of lines
all_strings_found=true
for string in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; do
    if ! grep -q "^$string$" $file; then
        echo "'"$string"'" "not found"
        all_strings_found=false
        break
    fi
done

if [ "$all_strings_found" ==  true ]; then
    echo "---> All strings found"
else
    echo "---> NOT all strings found"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick if you can load the whole file twice to memory:

```
str="
this is
a multiple
line
string"

# Read the whole file in variable
content=$(<some_file.txt)

# Replace str to nothing in content
repr=${content/${str}}

# Check if it's the same.
if [[ "$content" != "$repr" ]]; then
   # If it's not, means content contains str and it was removed.
   echo "Contains"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a perl one-liner:

```sh
if perl -0777 -sne '/$text/ or exit 1' -- -text="$str" "$file"
then
    echo Found
else
    echo not found
fi
```

The `-0777` option slurps the whole file into memory

Answer (score 0):

I like `case` statements for this.

```
$ cat script
str1="
this is
a multiple
line
string"
str2="$1"
f="$(<$0)"
case "$f" in
*"$str1"*) echo "String 1 exists"    ;;
        *) echo "String 1 not found" ;;
esac
case "$f" in
*"$str2"*) echo "String 2 exists"    ;;
        *) echo "String 2 not found" ;;
esac

$ ./script esac
String 1 exists
String 2 exists

$ ./script foo
String 1 exists
String 2 not found
```